# How to check variables changeable dependency in R?

Tags: r, regression, interaction, linear

I would be very thankful if somebody could help me and explain the answer in simple terms.

I have y, x, z variables. They are countinuous, no missing values. y is dependent variable, x and z independent. There is significant correlation between them (varies from 0.25 to 0.35).

My hypothesis is that when z is very high, then x and y dependency is linear (x goes bigger, y smaller).
When z is very low, then in the beginning the situation is the same (dependency is linear), but in the end (about last quarter) it changes to quadratic.

So basically there are two different relationships between x and y, but the nature of the relationship depends on z which is again a continuous variable.

How can I test this model? Is it possible doing linear regression or do I need to use something else?